# If I rescale the time in a differential equation, do I need to adjust the parameters?

Tags: ode, scaling

Imagine I have a differential equation and I have some data and the model is supposed to fit the data. If I now rescale the time in the range 0 to 1, do I need to adjust the parameters of the equations? How would one adjust them?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic for computational science but might be appropriate in math.stackexchange.

Comment: Actually, if we could see the structure of the equation it would be clearer if this question belongs more to math or to computational science

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Let's assume you have an ODE of the form
$$
  x'(t) = kx(t)
$$
and that your coefficient is $k=42$. If the physical units of $x$ are meters and of $t$ seconds, then what that really means is that $k=42 \frac{1}{s}$.

So now if you rescale time -- say, you want to measure time in minutes, you still have $k=42 \frac{1}{s}$ but you want to express this also in minutes, which would make it
$$
k=42 \frac{1}{s} = 42 \frac{1}{\frac{1}{60}\text{min}} = 42\times 60 \frac{1}{\text{min}} = 2520 \frac{1}{\text{min}}.
$$
That means, the coefficient is exactly the same as before, but it has a different numeric value that would have to be input into a program.